# vboxnetflt : NAT ok but rules not visible with iptables, how possible?

Tags: iptables, virtualbox, nat

This is just to improve my knowledge than to fix an issue.

How virtualbox NATing rules are invisible from iptables's host?

Debian 9.4.0
Virtualbox 5.2.8r121009

Answer (score 0):

To view the NAT rules use the following:

```
iptables -t nat -vnL
```

The command above run without the `-t` option to specify the `nat` table returns the rules from the default `filter` table. There are 5 tables in all.

Comment: Thank you datUser but I have quite good iptables knowledge.  :)

There are simply no rules (NATing or port forwarding) visible for the vboxnet0 interface.

Strange. The vboxnetflt  driver seems to bypass it somehow.